# Who was the first Christian to list the books of the Old Testament in the Lutheran bible?

Tags: bible, history, canon, lutheranism, protestant-bible

Who was the first Christian (not necessarily Lutheran) to list the books of the Old Testament in the Lutheran bible, without additions or subtractions, and without later changing his mind?

[This source](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/essay/the-biblical-canon/) mentions the influence of Josephus on the canon, but mentions no Christian.

Related: [When was the OT canon as used by Protestants finalized?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/450/when-was-the-ot-canon-as-used-by-protestants-finalized)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean "the first person to say that Lutherans should use these books from the OT"?

Comment: Yea I am also unsure about what this question is asking.

Comment: @DJClayworth - There is a list of books that are considered canon in the Old Testament of Lutheran bibles, correct? Who was the first Christian that made the same list and considered it canon?